# Activity no declarada en el android manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo un problema, he creado un nuevo activity para mi app y desde ese momento no se ejecuta. En el android manifest me aparece como no declarada. Alguien me puede decir como arreglarlo?

Este es el código del android manifest (la activity es LoginActivity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Saundier"
    tools:targetApi="31" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="false" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

El error que me da es este:

Unresolved class 'LoginActivity'

Espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Quizá te falta marcar `exported="true"`

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error:

> Unresolved class 'LoginActivity'

Indica que no puede encontrar la clase, debes revisar que la clase `LoginActivity` se encuentre al mismo nivel que `MainActivity`  en tu proyecto.

También debes verificar si necesitas el meta-data de LoginActivity, que en este caso su intent-filter debería ser definido con la propiedad `android:exported="true"`, este pudiera ser el problema:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:exported="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />
</activity>
```

Si tu clase se encuentra al mismo nivel que `LoginActivity` se encuentre al mismo nivel que `MainActivity`, entonces invalida caché:

`File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: Era eso, no estaba al mismo nivel, muchas gracias!!

Comment: "También debes verificar si necesitas el meta-data de LoginActivity, que en este caso su intent-filter debería ser definido con la propiedad android:exported="true", este pudiera ser el problema:"

Pero el `exported` solo es necesario si la activity se arranca "desde fuera" (otra aplicación, el propio sistema...) ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

¿Tienes una clase llamada `LoginActivity` en el mismo paquete que la `MainActivity`? Si no es así, tienes que declararla en ese paquete. O si no, apuntar al paquete correcto.

Por ejemplo, si tu aplicación es `com.example.miapp`, y tu clase main es `com.example.miapp` `.MainActivity`, la LoginActivity tiene que estar en `com.example.miapp` `.LoginActivity`. O apuntar al sitio correcto en el manifest (`com.example.miapp` `.activities.LoginActivity` por ejemplo).